# Access objects in Itemscontrol's ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my ItemsControl

```
<ItemsControl Name="empanadas_ic" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid Columns="2"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Name="emp_nombre_lbl"
               Content="{Binding nombre}"
               Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox Name="emp_cantidad_tb"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 TextChanged="emp_cantidad_tb_TextChanged" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is the ItemsSource Binding:

```
var context = new tres_empanadasEntities();
var v_empanadas = from t_empanadas in context.empanadas.ToList()
                  where t_empanadas.habilitado
                  select new{t_empanadas.id_empanada,
                             t_empanadas.nombre,
                             t_empanadas.precio};

this.empanadas_ic.ItemsSource = v_empanadas;
```

I achived to acces del Label and TextBox, but not de items in ItemsSource:

```
int cant;
String nombre;
ContentPresenter c;

for (int i = 0; i < empanadas_ic.Items.Count; i++){
  c = (ContentPresenter)empanadas_ic.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(empanadas_ic.Items[i]);

  // LABEL ACCESS
  nombre = (c.ContentTemplate.FindName("emp_nombre_lbl", c) as Label).Content.ToString();

  // TEXTBOX ACCESS
  cant = Convert.ToInt32((c.ContentTemplate.FindName("emp_cantidad_tb", c) as TextBox).Text);


}
```

In the same loop "for" i need to access every object in ItemsSource.

I know that Items perperty has the items, cause if i print

```
empanadas_ic.Items[i]
```

it shows me something like this:

```
{1, lalala, 123}
```

So... my objects are there, but cant rich them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ItemsSource` is set to an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

You could use the `dynamic` keyword to access the properties of it:

```
for (int i = 0; i<empanadas_ic.Items.Count; i++)
{
    dynamic obj = empanadas_ic.Items[i];
    var id_empanada = obj.id_empanada.ToString();
    var nombre = obj.nombre.ToString();
    //...
}
```

Or you could create a class:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string id_empanada { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string precio { get; set; }
}
```

...set the `ItemsSource` to an `IEnumerable` of this type:

```
var v_empanadas = from t_empanadas in context.empanadas.ToList()
                  where t_empanadas.habilitado
                  select new YourClass
                  {
                      id_empanada = t_empanadas.id_empanada,
                      nombre = t_empanadas.nombre,
                      precio = t_empanadas.precio
                  };
```

...and cast:

```
for (int i = 0; i<empanadas_ic.Items.Count; i++)
{
    YourClass obj = empanadas_ic.Items[i] as YourClass;
    if(obj != null)
    {
        var id_empanada = obj.id_empanada;
    }
    //...
}
```

Of course you should change type of the properties to string to whatever the real type of the entities are.